# Post-build event in VS has ceased to work correctly

Tags: visual-studio, post-build-event

Hello I developed some plugin for Revit, and after build copy required files in some directory via post-build event. It works for some years but today it has some strange behaviour.
I use such a script

```
      IF NOT "$(ConfigurationName)" == "DEV" (      
  MD "$(AppData)/Autodesk/ApplicationPlugins/$(ProjectName).bundle/Contents/$(ProjectName)/Resources/Images"
  copy /Y "$(ProjectDir)PackageContents.xml" "$(AppData)/Autodesk/ApplicationPlugins/$(ProjectName).bundle"
  copy /Y "$(ProjectDir)*.addin" "$(AppData)/Autodesk/ApplicationPlugins/$(ProjectName).bundle/Contents"
  xcopy /Y /E /R "$(ProjectDir)Resources/Images/*.png" "$(AppData)/Autodesk/ApplicationPlugins/$(ProjectName).bundle/Contents/$(ProjectName)/Resources/Images"  

  )
```

But instead, image files I have this inside Image folder
[File-Explorer Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlAT6.png)

Also, dlls file not copied.
I create a new solution, and it has some behaviour again.

If you have any idea please help me.

Comment: I suggest to go to the Tools->Options menu, choose Project&Solutions->Build&Run and then switch to the max verbosity level the MS-Build output. This should give you some insight to the command executed in the post-build event in case of errors. Be prepared to read a lot of stuff in the output window

Comment: Thank you, i hope it's help me figur out with this!

Answer (score -1):

A change post script, and now it work, but i don't know why previos have such behaviour

```
  IF NOT "$(ConfigurationName)" == "DEV" (
  MD "$(AppData)/Autodesk/ApplicationPlugins/$(ProjectName).bundle/Contents/$(ProjectName)"
  MD "$(AppData)/Autodesk/ApplicationPlugins/$(ProjectName).bundle/Contents/$(ProjectName)/Resources/Images"
  
  copy /Y "$(ProjectDir)/PackageContents.xml" "$(AppData)/Autodesk/ApplicationPlugins/$(ProjectName).bundle"
  copy /Y "$(ProjectDir)*.addin" "$(AppData)/Autodesk/ApplicationPlugins/$(ProjectName).bundle/Contents"

  xcopy /Y /E /R "$(ProjectDir)bin/$(Configuration)" "$(AppData)/Autodesk/ApplicationPlugins/$(ProjectName).bundle/Contents/$(ProjectName)"
  xcopy /Y /E /R "$(ProjectDir)Resources/Images" "$(AppData)/Autodesk/ApplicationPlugins/$(ProjectName).bundle/Contents/$(ProjectName)/Resources/Images"
  )
```